# app is "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" when my UITableView opens

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

My App that I have been working on crashes after the ViewDidAppears function. My Error:

```
Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3600.6.22/UITableView.m:8042
2017-02-08 01:58:53.747017 APP_Name[841:223668] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (<UITableView: 0x1018d4000; frame = (0 0; 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x174056d70>; layer = <CALayer: 0x174037200>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 200}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource (<App_Name.FindAParrty: 0x101242370>)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18d1611b8 0x18bb9855c 0x18d16108c 0x18dc1902c 0x193157d3c 0x193359bc4 0x193359d88 0x193347320 0x19335edec 0x1930fade8 0x193013a80 0x1904c19d8 0x1904b64cc 0x1904b638c 0x1904333e0 0x19045aa68 0x19045b488 0x18d10e0c0 0x18d10bcf0 0x18d10c180 0x18d03a2b8 0x18eaee198 0x1930817fc 0x19307c534 0x1000c5e58 0x18c01d5b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

After Doing research I read that one of the possible errors was that I didn't name a Reuse Identifier but I did and after that I am at a loss. I don't know if I'm Missing something or what the deal is.

Here is the TableView For Ref:

```
class FindAParty:UITableViewController{

    var partyData:NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
    //var user:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    override init(style: UITableViewStyle){
        super.init(style: style)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        //fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

    }


    @IBAction func loadData(){
        print ("Load Data went through")
        partyData.removeAllObjects()
        print ("Remove ALL Objeccts")
        let findPartyData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Party")
        print("PFQuery...")
        findPartyData.findObjectsInBackground{
            (objects:[PFObject]?, error:Error?)->Void in

            if error != nil {

                print("Error")


            }else{

                for object in objects!{

                    let party:PFObject = object as PFObject
                    self.partyData.add("party")
                    }

                let array:NSArray = self.partyData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects as NSArray
                self.partyData = NSMutableArray(array: array)

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.loadData()
        print("View Did Appear")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("ViewDidLoad")
        //self.loadData()
        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // #pragma mark - Table view data source

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView?) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return partyData.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell? {
        let cell:FindAPartyCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath! as IndexPath) as! FindAPartyCell

        let party:PFObject = self.partyData.object(at: indexPath!.row) as! PFObject

        cell.typeOfPartyLabel.alpha = 0
        cell.timeOfPartyLabel.alpha = 0
        cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 0

        cell.typeOfPartyLabel.text = party.object(forKey: "partyTitle") as? String
        cell.timeOfPartyLabel.text = party.object(forKey: "partyTime") as? String
        cell.usernameLabel.text = party.object(forKey: "Username") as? String

       // var dataFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        //dataFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
        //cell.timestampLabel.text = dataFormatter.stringFromDate(sweet.createdAt)

        let findUser:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
        findUser.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: party.object(forKey: "Username")!)



        findUser.findObjectsInBackground {
            (objects:[PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in // Changes NSError to Error
            if error == nil{

                let user:PFUser = (objects)!.last as! PFUser
                cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                    cell.typeOfPartyLabel.alpha = 1
                    cell.timeOfPartyLabel.alpha = 1
                    cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 1
                })
            }
        }


        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share screenshot of storyboard-where you have given identifier to cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are using old delegate methods of the Table View, use these:

   ```
   func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return xxx
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return xxx
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FindAPartyCell

       return cell
   }
   ```
2. Are you sure that your prototype `Cell` Identifier is assigned with `FindAPartyCell` in IB.
3. Try not to perform `findUser.findObjectsInBackground` operation inside `cellForRowAt` method.

Comment: Now I'm Getting this Error:  `Could not cast value of type 'Swift._NSContiguousString' (0x1082c90e8) to 'PFObject' (0x1057c1e98).
(lldb)`

Comment: this line?  `let party:PFObject = self.partyData.object(at: indexPath!.row) as! PFObject`

Comment: Yes that is the Line

Comment: Print `self.partyData.object(at: indexPath!.row)`, you will see that the output is a `String `not `PFObject`. So basically you are forcibly casting `String` to `PFObject`.

Comment: That is what I had Originally However when I put that It causes an error and Xcode tells me to Put : `as!PFobject`

Comment: what happens if you use this? `let party = self.partyData.object(at: indexPath!.row) `

Comment: @Jbarfield101 : Were you able to resolve that issue?

Comment: The App crashed once again `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Swift._NSContiguousString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: Do one thing, post a new question for this issue, then it will get large audience to resolve it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151851/terminating-app-due-to-swift-nscontiguousstring-to-pfobject?noredirect=1#comment71470177_42151851