# Terminating App due to 'Swift._NSContiguousString' to 'PFObject'

Tags: uitableview, parse-platform, swift3

I'm Stuck on this issue and I have tried different 'fixes' for this issue however nothing seems to work. Code for Ref: 
class FindAParty:UITableViewController{

```
    var partyData:NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
        //var user:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

        override init(style: UITableViewStyle){
            super.init(style: style)

        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            //fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

        }


        @IBAction func loadData(){
            print ("Load Data went through")
            partyData.removeAllObjects()
            print ("Remove ALL Objeccts")
            let findPartyData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Party")
            print("PFQuery...")
            findPartyData.findObjectsInBackground{
                (objects:[PFObject]?, error:Error?)->Void in

                if error != nil {

                    print("Error")


                }else{

                    for object in objects!{

                        let party:PFObject = object as PFObject
                        self.partyData.add("party")
                        }

                    let array:NSArray = self.partyData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects as NSArray
                    self.partyData = NSMutableArray(array: array)

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }
            }
        }

        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            self.loadData()
            print("View Did Appear")
        }
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            print("ViewDidLoad")
            //self.loadData()
            // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
            // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

            // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
            // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        // #pragma mark - Table view data source
        override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return partyData.count
        }


        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FindAPartyCell

//Error Happens Below
            let party:PFObject = self.partyData.object(at: indexPath.row) as! PFObject





            cell.typeOfPartyLabel.alpha = 0
            cell.timeOfPartyLabel.alpha = 0
            cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 0

            cell.typeOfPartyLabel.text = party.object(forKey: "partyTitle") as? String
            cell.timeOfPartyLabel.text = party.object(forKey: "partyTime") as? String
            cell.usernameLabel.text = party.object(forKey: "Username") as? String

           // var dataFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            //dataFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
            //cell.timestampLabel.text = dataFormatter.stringFromDate(sweet.createdAt)

            let findUser:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
            findUser.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: party.object(forKey: "Username")!)



            findUser.findObjectsInBackground {
                (objects:[PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in // Changes NSError to Error
                if error == nil{

                    let user:PFUser = (objects)!.last as! PFUser
                    cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username

                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                        cell.typeOfPartyLabel.alpha = 1
                        cell.timeOfPartyLabel.alpha = 1
                        cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 1
                    })
                }
            }


            return cell
        }}
```

Someone recommended changing : `let party:PFObject = self.partyData.object(at: indexPath.row) as! PFObject`

to :

```
let party = self.partyData.object(at: indexPath!.row)
```

However this did not fix it and I am at a loss to how I should fix it the app build successfully and every other aspect of it runs however this is the only part that fails. I am using Parse and Amazon as my backend.

Comment: **Never** use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift. You throw away the important type information and this causes all your problems. `partyData` is supposed to be `var partyData = [PFObject]()` (non-optional!)

Comment: So Should I use just a normal Array?

Comment: You should use a Swift `Array`

Comment: Wouldn't This make the app unable to `.removeAllObjects` and wouldn't be able to `.add(PartyData)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the data source array

```
var partyData = [PFObject]()
```

and change `loadData()` to

```
    @IBAction func loadData(){
        print ("Load Data went through")
        partyData.removeAll()
        print ("Remove ALL Objeccts")
        let findPartyData = PFQuery(className: "Party")
        print("PFQuery...")
        findPartyData.findObjectsInBackground {
            (objects:[PFObject]?, error:Error?)->Void in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            } else{
                if let objects = objects {
                    self.partyData = objects.reversed()
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and get a row:

```
let party = self.partyData[indexPath.row]
```

Finally replace in `cellForRowAt`

```
if error == nil {
   let user:PFUser = (objects)!.last as! PFUser
```

with

```
if users = objects as? [PFUser], !users.isEmpty {
   let user = users.last!
```

Comment: What should I do about this Line now that it says member has no object. `let party:PFObject = self.partyData.object(at: indexPath.row) as! PFObject`

Comment: I updated the answer. Do you see the dramatically reduced syntax?

Comment: Where do I declare the Users Object because when I replace that code it gives me an error